# Nginx ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose

Need help setting up Ngin. I need to set up https for my service

This is the service configuration

```
events {}
http {
server {
listen 80;
listen \[::\]:443 ssl;
server_name example.com localhost;

        # SSL-сертификаты
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/example.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/example.key;
    
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        keepalive_timeout 70;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://example_app:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }

}
```

This is the docker-compose.yml configuration

```
version: '3'

networks:
  imggen_network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"
    volumes:
     - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
     - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    depends_on:
     - example_app
    networks:
     - imggen_network
```

The service works on port http://127.0.0.1:8000/, but when accessing https://127.0.0.1:8000/ it gives an error

This site cannot provide a secure connection. Site 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
Run network diagnostics in Windows.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

The service works on port http://127.0.0.1:8000/, but when accessing https://127.0.0.1:8000/ it gives an error

This site cannot provide a secure connection. Site 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
Run network diagnostics in Windows.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR